# Thymeleaf не подключает css файл

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Попробовал много вариантов, в том числе и с официального сайта thymeleaf.
 Я знаю, что эту тему уже обсуждали, но варианты, которые предлагали для решения мне не помогли

`<link th:href="@{/styles/css/main.css}" rel="stylesheet" />`

```
h2 {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

strong {
font-weight: 700;
background-color: yellow;
}

p {
font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: cssandjs.css/main.css? странный у вас путь конечно, ооччень интересно почему не работает

Comment: А вы храните сам файл?

Comment: если не разберетесь с тем, что Николай написал - маякните -я подробный ответ напишу. Здесь для уведомления нужно через собаку обращаться(@МихаилРебров ).  Ну или в телегу можете мне написать. Она у меня в профиле указана.

Comment: @МихаилРебров помогите разобраться самому не получается

Comment: написал ответ - если и с ним возникнут сложности маякни под моим постом или в телеграмме - помогу чем смогу

Comment: да Большое спасибо за информативное объяснение все работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нетерпеливым мотать в конец поста.
Всем кто тем, хочет разобраться читать все

## Thymeleaf

Начнем с того, почему не работает: `th:href="@{/styles/css/main.css}"`
`@{...}` - это всего лишь компонент, который помогает формировать URL-выражения.
**Например:**
Из этого: `<a th:href="@{/order/details(id=${orderId},type=${orderType})}">...</a>`
Помогает делать это: `<a href="/myapp/order/details?id=23&amp;type=online">...</a>`

И что самое важное: он не призван предоставлять доступ к файлам, которые находятся в ресурсах.
 Вся его область ответственности не выходит за рамки работы с шаблонами, а работа с ресурсами лежит за этими границами.

Другими словами фраза `Thymeleaf не подключает css файл` вынесенная в заголовок не имеет смысла, потому что `Thymeleaf` и не должен ничего подключать.

## 404 ошибка

Далее разберемся с тем, что происходит в браузере.
Браузер загружает страницу и видит там тег

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/css/main.css"/>
```

после чего выполняет запрос `GET http://localhost:8080/styles/css/main.css`
получает ответ от веб-сервера о том, что по данному адресу ничего не найдено, выводит сообщение об ошибке в консоль и страница остается без стилей.

Здесь нам интересно разобраться в том, что это за веб-сервер такой и где он находится.

Отвечаю: по умолчанию в `Spring Boot` используется веб-сервер `Apache Tomcat`.
 Фактически при запуске своего `Spring Boot Application` вы сначала запускаете свой веб-сервер, на котором `Spring Boot` автоматически деплоит ваше веб-приложение.

В этом легко убедиться посмотрев в вывод консоли при запуске Вашего приложения.
[image: логи Tomcatа]

К слову это относительное новшество. До появления проекта `Spring Boot` не было встроенного веб-сервера и всем приходилось самостоятельно деплоить приложения на отдельно стоящие веб-сервера, коих работает на JVM огромное множество: Tomcat, Jetty, Netty, JBoss, WildFly, GlassFish, WebLogic и др. Добавить встроенный было решено для удобства и быстроты разработки, собственно это и было основной целью `Spring Boot`.

Возвращаясь к теме: абсолютно все HTTP запросы принимает веб-сервер, после чего в зависимости от своих настроек, он может передать их одному из развернутых на него приложений (в Вашем случае веб-сервер Apache Tomcat передает все запросы вашему приложению), после чего уже принятый запрос - это Ваша ответственность. Ваше приложение обрабатывает запрос, возвращает ответ веб-серверу, после чего данный HTTP Response отправляется от веб-сервера к клиенту(браузеру).

Такая вот цепочка.

**Замечание:**

> В данном случае я немного упростил маршрут движения HTTP запроса и
> ответа.
>  На самом деле, помимо web-сервера есть еще понятие
> Application Server.
>  Если просто то Application Server это
> контейнер, который может запускать другие приложения, и который может
> принимать и отправлять запросы, при этом принятые запросы он
> перенаправляет запущенным в контейнере приложениям.
>  Простой
> веб-сервер этого не умеет. Например Apache HTTP Server(не путать с
> Tomcat) или nginx. Эти сервера могут отдавать статический контент
> расположенный на сервере(обычный файлы), выступать в качестве прокси
> серверов и балансировщиков. Но вот из коробки запускать другие
> приложения они не умеют (хотя имеют модули, с помощью которых можно
> этого достичь).
>  По сути любой Application Server является по
> определению и веб-сервером, потому что он может принимать
> http-запросы. Поэтому я не стал усложнять данную схему и называл
> Tomcat веб-сервером.
>  Но в производственной среде часто перед
> Application Server'ами ставят более высокопроизводительные
> веб-сервера(например тот же nginx), которые выступают
> балансировщиками, прокси, и нередко отвечают за раздачу статики.
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Справка:**

- [Ссылка на Tomcat на сайте Apache Founadtion](https://tomcat.apache.org/)
- [Ссылка на Tomcat в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)
- ["Сервер приложений" в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)
- ["Веб сервер" в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)

## Обработка запроса в приложении

Итак, вот запрос пришел к нам в приложение: что дальше?

Одним из первых этот запрос обрабатывает маршрутизатор(Router).
Он берет запрос и сверяет его со всеми зарегистрированными в приложениями маршрутами. Если он находит совпадение, то он передает запрос в контроллер и методу указанными в маршруте. Если он не нашел совпадение, то приложение отправляет ответ 404. И как ты понимаешь, в твоем случае случилось именно это.

И я думаю у тебя назрел вопрос: *А почему же он не нашел ни одного подходящего маршрута?*
Ответ простой: *Потому что его не было.*

Посуди сам: Зачем нам по умолчанию вкладывать маршрут, который отдаёт статику из папки resources?

- А что если наше приложение будет REST API, и ему вообще не нужно будет отдавать никаких стилей?
- А что если в папке с ресурсами лежит файлы доступ к которым мы никак не хотим открывать?
- А что если наши стили лежат не в папке с ресурсами а в какой-то произвольной папке на сервере...или вообще скажем: на другом хосте?

Получается, что включенная по умолчанию передача ресурсов приносила бы больше вреда чем пользы.

И тогда следующим логичным вопрос будет: 
**Откуда и как маршрутизатор получает список маршрутов.**
на самом деле способов много, но наc сейчас больше всего интересует тот, который мы будем чаще всего использовать в Spring Boot приложении, а именно аннотации.
При запуске приложения определяются все классы помеченные аннотацией `@Controller`, и все методы, помеченные аннотациями:

- `@RequestMapping`
- `@GetMapping`
- `@PostMapping`
- `@PutMapping`
- `@PatchMapping`
- `@DeleteMapping`

И добавляет в маршруты путь указанный в аннотации, контроллер и метод, к которым привязана аннотация и HTTP- метод:

- для `@GetMapping` это GET
- для `@PostMapping` это POST
- для `@PutMapping` это PUT
- для `@PatchMapping` это PATCH
- для `@DeleteMapping` это DELETE
- для `@RequestMapping` это ВСЕ ВЫШЕПЕРЕЧИСЛЕННЫЕ МЕТОДЫ

Соответственно, когда приходит запрос, маршрутизатор ищет совпадение пути и метода указанного в маршрути и при совпадении передает управление, указанному контроллеру в указанный метод.

Зная, все вышесказанное может возникнуть идея:
**А почему бы не взять и самому не отдать этот самый CSS файл**

## Кастомный метод отдачи статики

Я начал именно с данного способа, потому что Вы должны понимать, что примерно происходит, когда Вы запрашиваете некий файл из папки ресурсов.

**Что нам нужно сделать:**

- создать класс контроллера (пусть это будет ResourceController) и пометить его аннотацией `@Controller`
- Создать метод (пусть это будет styles) и пометить его аннотацией `@GetMapping` в которую мы пропишем необходимый путь.
- Получить содержимое файла из ресурсов
- Привести содержимое файла к строке и отправить его в качестве ответа сервера.

**Что нам важно помнить и учитывать:**

- Для того чтобы браузер смог понять что данные, которые мы ему возвращаем являются стилями, в ответе сервера необходимо установить заголовок: `"Content-Type: text/css"`
- Для того чтобы вернуть тело запроса непосредственно из контроллера необходимо установить над методом аннотацию `@ResponseBody`, в таком случае контроллер не будет передавать управление другим компонентам
- Для того чтобы вернуть HTTP Response с телом и с заголовками мы воспользуемся классом `ResponseEntity`, в тело которого мы передадим содержимое файла, а заголовки укажем с помощью класса `HttpHeaders`
- Для получения содержимого файлов из папки ресурсов мы можем воспользоваться методом `getResourceAsStream` текущего 'ClassLoader''а.

```java
package com.example.TestSpring;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

@Controller
public class ResourceController {

    @GetMapping("/styles/css/{code}.css")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> styles(@PathVariable("code") String code) throws IOException {
        // получаем содержимое файла из папки ресурсов в виде потока
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("static/css/"+code+".css");
        // преобразуем поток в строку
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        while((line = bf.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        
        // создаем объект, в котором будем хранить HTTP заголовки
        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders= new HttpHeaders();
        // добавляем заголовок, который хранит тип содержимого
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/css; charset=utf-8");
        // возвращаем HTTP ответ, в который передаем тело ответа, заголовки и статус 200 Ok
        return new ResponseEntity<String>( sb.toString(), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Обратите внимание на то, что:**

- в маршруте я указал `/styles/css/{code}.css`
  `{code}` - это плейсхолдер, и он же является переменной пути (Path Variable)
  Это значит, что данный метод будет обрабатывать все запросы такого вида
  /styles/css/main.css, /styles/css/admin.css, /styles/css/application.css и пр
- Для того чтобы получить значение данного плейсхолдера, я указал в параметрах метода параметр `String code` и установил перед ним аннотацию `@PathVariable("code")` для того чтобы Spring мог связать плейсхолдер `{code}` с данным параметром метода
- заметьте, что путь в маршруте (/styles/css/{code}.css) и путь к файлу относительно папки ресурсов ("/static/css/" + code + ".css") отличаются.
  я старался максимально соответствовать вашему примеру и в нем была указана именно такая ссылка на css(/styles/css/main.css) и именно такой путь к нему в папке ресурсов (static/css/{code}.css)
  если это уже не соответствует действительности, то внесите соответствующие правки в ваш код

В результате всех проделанных действий и запуска приложения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, сервер успешно вернул мне ответ с css файлом. В данном файле было одно правило, которое закрашивает фон в красный цвет и как видите, оно успешно применилось.

Данный метод я проиллюстрировал за тем чтобы Вы понимали как происходит отдача ресурсов, и для того чтобы Вы могли выходить из более сложных ситуаций:

- когда файлы стилей находятся  в какой-то папке на сервере за рамками Вашего проекта
- когда Вам стили формируются через админку и хранятся в базе данных
- когда Вы пользуетесь спригном в связке с другими фреймворками, которые переопределяют FrontController и т.д.

Также этот метод вы можете использовать и для того, чтобы отдавать другие ресурсы: изображения и пр.

После всего этого Вы можете мне сказать:
*"Здорово конечно...спасибо. А чо так сложно то? Нельзя как нибудь полегче?"*
И я отвечу: *"Можно!"*

## Отдача статики встроенными средствами SpringMVC

Несмотря на все те минусы, которые я описал в начале, отдача файлов из папки ресурсов по HTTP обладает и своими плюсами.
И главный плюс - это простота.
Если нам не нужно хранить стили на каком-то другом сервере или в CDN (сети доставки и распространения контента), если не нужно их хранить в базе данных или как-то предварительно подготавливать и компилировать их, если у нас достаточно простое приложение и нас устраивает, что стили находятся непосредственно рядом с приложением, то почему бы и нет!
Это просто и удобно, когда нам не нужно разрабатывать какое-то мега-сложное и монструозное приложение.

И да: просто отдавать все файлы подряд из папки ресурсов небезопасно...там могут быть и конфигурационные файлы, и настройки с паролями.

Но никто нам не мешает выделить какую-то отдельную область в которой будет храниться статика и настроить на отдачу только данную папку, при этом все остальные ресурсы останутся в безопасности.
Вот это уже вполне приемлемый вариант.
И как водится для этого уже есть встроенные инструменты:

Для того, чтобы настроить отдачу ресурсов нам нужно:

- создать класс конфигурации.
- сообщить спрингу что данный класс, будет использоваться для настройки, для этого над классом необходимо указать аннотацию `@Configuration`
- сообщить спрингу что мы нам потребуется поддержка SpringMVC, для этого мы указываем аннотацию @EnableWebMvc
- дальше нам нужно будет имплементировать интерфейс `WebMvcConfigurer`, собственно спринг для настройки просто будет поочереди вызывать методы, указанные в данном интерфейсе. По умолчанию они ничего не делают. Нам просто нужно переопределить необходимые нам методы.
- и в конце нам нужно определить ОБРАБОТЧИКИ РЕСУРСОВ. По их названию понятно что они отвечают за обработку ресурсов. Для этого нам нужно будет переопределить метод `addResourceHandlers` и в нем настроить обработку ресурсов.

**Приступим:**

```java
package com.example.TestSpring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/styles/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
    }
}
```

**Что здесь происходит?:**

- мы получаем объект реестра обработчика ресурсов
- далее мы обращаемся к этому реестру и говорим ему что нам нужно обрабатывать HTTP запросы соответствующие шаблону: `/styles/css/**`
- также мы говорим, что все файлы, запрашиваемые по указанному пути стоит искать в этом месте `classpath:/static/css/`

**На что стоит обратить внимание:**

- еще раз прошу обратить внимание, что у нас отличается URL и путь
  ссылке `http://localhost:8080/styles/css/main.css` будет соответствовать файл `/static/css/main.css` в папке ресурсов
- мы указываем просим реестр искать папку относительно CLASSPATH
  в нашем случае папка ресурсов находится в CLASSPATH, поэтому нам допустимо так указывать.
- И также стоит обратить внимание, что лучше не использовать данный метод, с контроллером из прошлого пункта, а если и есть такая необходимость, то нужно удостовериться в том, что Ваш контроллер и обработчик ресурсов из конфигурации не будут обрабатывать одинаковых урлов. В таком случае запрос будет обрабатываться по принципу: "Кто первый встал того и тапки"

Под конец добавлю, что ты можешь замапить и другие ресурсы:

```java
package com.example.TestSpring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
    }
}
```

и ты получишь следующую маршрутизацию:

- `http://localhost:8080/styles/css/main.css` -> `/static/css/main.css`
- `http://localhost:8080/images/test.jpg` -> `/static/images/test.jpg`
- `http://localhost:8080/js/script.js` -> `/static/js/script.js`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/cssandjs.css/main.css}"/>
```

Если это не сработает измените расположение файлов css.
Хранить css необходимо по такому пути.

```
src/main/resources/static/css
```

Дополнение
Необходимо создать class

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
```

И сделать метод

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/" + uploadPath + "/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/email/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/**");
    }
```

Comment: сделал так проблема не решилась?

Comment: Смотри дополнение

Comment: ну вот... только собрался писать ответ и на тебе...только расшифруйте ТС что это за класс, что это за метод и что там можно и нужно указывать...плюс у вас в примере не самые очевидные примеры.

Comment: в какой папке его создать и где вызывать этот метод

Comment: Подробное описание https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Answer (score 0):

Дтя тех, кто использует Spring Security (SecurityConfiguration), нужно добавить разрешение в методе `configure(HttpSecurity http)`, например:

```
.antMatchers("/css/style.css","/js/bootstrap.js","/css/style.scss").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попытался сделать как сказано в большом ответе сверху, не получилось.
Пока точно не разобрался почему у меня работает именно так, но может кому-то поможет.

Конфигурационный класс:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

link в html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/button.css">
```

Путь до самого файла css: ***src/main/resources/static/css/button.css***