# Не подключается css к html

Tags: html, css, spring, thymeleaf

html страница

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3" lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" object="${registrationRequest}" method="post">
    <div class="dws-input">

    <div><label> Email : <input type="text"  field="*{login}"  name="login"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password"  field="*{password}" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/></div>
        </br>
        <a href="auth" >Sign In</a>
    </div>
</form>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css файл

```
a{
    color: #fff;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image: структура проекта]

Comment: в браузере F12, сеть; посмотрите идет ли запрос на css, на какой адрес; что сервер отвечает

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/css/login.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: ну вот, сервер вернул json, видимо с ошибкой; к css/html вопрос не относится; что за сервер/фреймворк; может для темплейтов и статики там разные папки; или на css преобразователь какой-то настроен

Comment: попробуй абсолютный путь: href="/css/login.css"

Comment: нужно было указать что данный вопрос касается Spring и Thymeleaf, я отвечал уже на похожий вопрос здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211649/thymeleaf-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-css-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/1212731#1212731

Comment: Если поможет - отпишитесь - я проставлю ссылку на дубликат. Если не поможет - тоже отпишитесь и я постараюсь помочь