# IMG can not be finded

Tags: html5, spring, spring-boot, img

У меня есть html файл со следующим тегом

```
<img src="images/sweater.png" alt="Sweater">
```

Файл находится в resourses/templates/images/sweater.png

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я навожу курсор на тег, показывает, что файл присутствует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в моем приложении оно не появляется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема??

Comment: Это Spring Boot приложение, а как правильно поступить тогда и почему подсвечивается при наведении на тег нужная фотография?

Comment: Ой, я не обратил внимания на теги. Ну в любом случае редактор скорее всего ничего не знает про настройки Spring Boot и показывает что попало, что совсем не обязательно совпадает с поведением, прописанным в Spring Boot

Comment: я здесь подробно описываю данный вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211649/thymeleaf-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-css-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/1212731#1212731 (в данном вопросе пользователь жалуется на то что CSS не может подключить, но смысл один и тот же - нет понимания как вообще эти ресурсы в браузере появляются и что нужно настроить для их отдачи)