# Spring boot не подключает css к html странице

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, boot

почему то не отображаются стили на html странице. Стили лежат в папке `static.css`.
Что я делаю не так? 
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

**main_page.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css" type="text/css" th:href="@{/static/css/main.css}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="hello">
    hello
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.css:**

```
.hello
{
    width: 123px;
    color: blue;
    background: darkorange;
}
```

**MainController:**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String mainPage()
    {
        return "main_page";
    }
}
```

**Application:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SroApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SroApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

***MVCConfig:**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/styles/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: настройки MVC делали где-нибудь?

Comment: приложите скрин структуры папки ресурсов

Comment: у меня есть похожий ответ.там я очень подробно рассказываю подобный кейс https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211649/thymeleaf-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-css-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/1212731#1212731

Comment: посмотрите его - если не поможет - напишите.

Comment: фактически можно использовать способ в самом конце ответа (`registry.addResourceHandler()`). все что было до этого - для понимания самого процесса отдачи статики

Comment: @МихаилРебров да, в MVC прописал handler, но это не помогло

Comment: а почему тогда href в верстке не /styles/css/main.css?

Comment: И странно что у вас папка как пакет выглядит. Откройте ее в обычном проводнике или любом другом файловом менеджере и посмотрите: может вы просто создали папку static.css(с точкой) вместо вложенных папок

Comment: @МихаилРебров две вложенные папки, проверил, все окей

Comment: Все... Понятно сейчас ответ напишу

Comment: Если все решено, то см: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрим внимательно на данную строку:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/menu.css}">
```

С первого(да и со второго) раза я не заметил,
но потом увидел следующее:

```
th:href="@{/css/menu.css}"
```

так не стоит делать - вы просто заменяете то, что было написано в атрибуте href...

**В вашем случае тег должен выглядеть так:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
```

или так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/css/main.css}" type="text/css"/>
```

Но не то и другое одновременно, и не противоречащие друг другу значения.
А в ссылке нужно указывать тот путь который вы указали в `MvcConfig`

Если здесь `/styles/css/`

```
.addResourceHandler("/styles/css/**")
```

то и здесь `/styles/css/`

```
href="/styles/css/main.css"
```